# How to get rid of the error that appears when I read the csv file without indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

The following error appears:

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-43485697095e> in <module>
----> 1 d_test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index = False)

TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'
```

My code:

```
d_test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

why do you use `index=False`?

`pd.read_csv('filename.csv')` don't get `index` as input. you got error because use `index` as input for function `read_csv`.

Comment: Yes exactly but then how can I delete the indexes when working with the dataframe further?